# Why CS1501 error msg 18+ overloads and 0 arguments?

Tags: c#

I am enrolled in a beginner C# online course.
Learning about how to deal with coding errors is mostly for the student to resolve.
Visual Studio 2019 is the preferred course IDE.
Some VS error messages are easy while others are very tricky to understand and resolve.
I am working on an assessable item - so not posting the full program code here.
A key section of code is throwing error CS1501 - I have searched internet for solution though do not understand how those maters fit with my situation.
Key code section as follows:

```
 int abc;
 abc = Console.ReadLine(Convert.ToInt32());
```

> Curly red lines in VS are under 'ToInt32'   with error notes: int
> Convert.ToInt32(bool value) (18+ overloads)      CS1501 No overload
> for method 'ToInt32' takes 0 arguments.

Thanks.

Comment: You likely want `Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine())`  That will pass the result of reading a line from the console to `ToInt32` which will then try to convert it to an `int`.  The error is due to the fact that `Convert.ToInt32` takes an argument and you don't give it one, and also `Console.ReadLine` does not take an argument, but you do pass one to it.

Answer (score 4):

You have it the wrong way around

```
 int abc;
 abc = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

---

**The long story**

`Console.ReadLine()` returns a string

`Convert.ToInt32` takes an input (of varying type) to return an `int`

If you look at all the overloads for [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netcore-3.1) you will soon notice there are no variants that take 0 arguments. Which is what the compiler is telling you.

> No overload for method 'ToInt32' takes 0 arguments.

---

However, never use `Convert.ToInt32` to parse user input

Use [`int.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netcore-3.1) instead

> Converts the string representation of a number to its 32-bit signed
> integer equivalent. A return value indicates whether the operation
> succeeded.

```
int abc;
var input = Console.ReadLine();

if(!int.TryParse(input, out abc)) 
   // user couldn't type a number, do something else instead
```